# Three married couples on a rectangular table with 6 chairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> There is a rectangular table as shown in the figure, which has three chairs on two sides each. There married couples sit on these chairs.

[image]

> Find the number of ways in which couples sit either in front of each other or adjacently.

What I tried:

Case 1: All couples are sitting in front of each other:
$$3!\times2^3$$

$2^3$ is the number of ways in which the member of a couple can interchange the position and $3!$ is the permutation of the columns.

Case 2: One couple is sitting in front of each other and two adjacently.

[image]

$$2\times 3! \times 2^3$$

$2^3$ is the number of ways in which the member of a couple can interchange the position and $3!$ is the permutations of the couples and $2$ is because there are two ways of arrangement as shown in the figure.

So total number of ways: $48+96=144$

But the given answer is $112$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your calculation.

Comment: According to their solution, for case 2, the Number of ways=$4\times 2^4$. They haven't provided any justification. :/

Comment: Since the given answer is not divisible by $3!$ it cannot be correct.

Comment: Permuting the three couples gives a clear factor of $3$ for each pattern.

Comment: $4\times 2^4$ is weird !

Comment: Ok. Thanks. There is another part of this question, where they are asking the number of ways exactly one couple sits adjacent/in front of each other. Should I edit that into this or ask a new question? (I earlier thought that I might have a misunderstanding so I didn't ask it earlier)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

This is easy to see as follows.

There are $3$ fundamentally different arrangements.

The three couples can be permuted in $3!$ ways.

The partners can be permuted in $2^3$ ways.

The product of these is $144$.